# Turtlebot rviz "Frame [map] does not exist" error

Tags: ros, rviz, frame, openni-kinect, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turtlebot_bringup kinect.launch seems to work-no errors. However rviz from Workstation (openni-kinect indexed) shows black window with Global Status Error "Frame [map] does not exist" and cannot add Camera or Pointcloud2. For what it matters, the Kinect Camera does work with the Android teleop app.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31605/turtlebot-rviz-%22frame-%5Bmap%5D-does-not-exist%22-error/) by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2012-04-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

/map frame is broadcast usually by the navigation stack eg. refer to amcl or gmapping in turtlebot tutorial. Just launching kinect.launch will not give the /map frame.

To add Camera view in rviz, you can change the global frame to one of the kinect's frame (eg depth) or /odom if the robot is up and running.

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1